# Mag wheels for a hybrid

Tags: wheels

So I have a Giant Escape 3, M size frame, 21 speed shifting, 700c wheels. Is it possible to put on some magnesium wheels? To give it sort of like a fixed look. If so, any suggestions? Thanks!

[image: giant escape 3]

Comment: What you really mean is: are magnesium 700c wheels with regular road dropout spacing and a freehub on the rear available?.

Comment: Well, there are, but they are a bad idea for many reasons and the end result won't look like a fixie.

Comment: You can use any wheel you like as long as its physical surfaces match the dimensions of your existing wheels.  So that's the brake track, the freehub for the cassette to mount onto, and the ends of the hubs to fit both sets of dropouts.   This could be expensive, or very expensive, so you could not leave the bike locked up outside anymore.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a fixed look"   ?   I'm guessing that you are expecting a deeper section rim, not a mag wheel.

Answer (score 3):

You can put on whatever wheels you would like provided they have the right hub spacing, diameter, brake type, and freehub body for the drivetrain you are using.

Considering mag wheels are typically only used on fixie and track bikes which are single speed, the hubs would likely not allow you to use gears. Also track bikes don't have brakes so it would be hard to find a mag wheel with a rim brake track.

Overall I would not recommend putting mag wheels on this bike.